# Call custom emergency number from lockscreen

Tags: lock-screens, 5.1-lollipop, emergency-calls

Ok, basically, what I want, is to provide Android phone to child, locked by passcode (or gesture), and allow the child to call parents (two numbers) from locked device.

My current available target device is SDK 22, Android 5.1, but I will not limit the answers to this target.

What is not correct answer:

- something along the lines of setting ICE info, this won't allow to call, just to display ICE phone numbers
- modifying the SIM card data, as this is not possible generally and not available in my case
- solutions requiring ROOTing the device, as this is not possible in my case
- solutions using CALL_PRIVILEGED, as this permission is protected and not achievable without ROOTing the device or having custom ROM
- Solutions using Samsung or other proprietary emergency dialers, as the devices I target, do not use any such measure, and look like [this](https://drfone.wondershare.com/images/article/2017/10/15076378953268.jpg)

What I've tried to do is

- Creating custom notification intent on the lockscreen, which would use ACTION_CALL intent and `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` permission

  - this is not working solution, as CALL_PHONE requires unlocking the device
- Creating custom notification intent on the lockscreen, which would send out SMS to pre-defined numbers

  - this works, however it might be pricey, and I consider this the last resort option
  - this also does/might not resolve the `emergency` cases, child might got into, because the reaction time depends on parents having the phone volume up and calling back right-away

Comment: Your question turned up in close vote queue, so I want to clarify that whether you are asking from a developer's perspective or an end-user's perspective?

Comment: @Firelord both actually, i'd be more than happy for solution which suits end-users, however I'm capable of accepting dev solution and turning that into end-user solution (ie through github/fdroid)

Answer (score 2):

The feature you are looking for already exists in [Android 7.0+](https://www.androidpolice.com/2016/03/11/android-n-feature-spotlight-add-and-display-emergency-information-on-your-lockscreen/). Upgrade your device if you can.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I sincerely cannot upgrade the devices, however, what you've posted is what I mentioned in incorrect answers as first option, this will only set ICE emergency info, but not allow you to call said emergency number if it is not in SIM card (where default 911, 112, etc. emergency numbers are persisted)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what ICE info is but do you not want the ability to call custom contacts from the lock screen without unlocking? As you can see in the first image there is an "add contact" button to do so. I've done it on my phone as well, can be seen [here](https://i.imgur.com/3aNPIIf.jpg).

Comment: thank you, are you actually able to call the contacts from the posted screenshot without unlocking device? ICE info is abbreviation of "In Case of Emergency", which is exactly what you've posted

Comment: Yep, can call without unlocking, hence the suggestion to upgrade if you can.